# How can I run commands and save the output using a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to run the following commands:

```
NTLast.exe
NTLast.exe -f
NTLast.exe -r
NTLast.exe -r -f
```

This .exe is stored in `C:\Win Live Response`.

So I have tested with the following:

`start "" "C:\Win Live Response\"NTLast.exe -f > test.txt`

and

`start "" "C:\Win Live Response\"NTLast.exe -f >> test.txt`

But none of those is saving the output in the test.txt

Please help

Comment: You don't need to use `start`. Your double quotes should end after `NTLast.exe`, not before. What output does the application produce when you run in from a command prompt?

Comment: If it's still outputting to the screen, you may need to use `2>>test.txt` instead of `>>test.txt`. Sometimes software misuses stderr.

Comment: @k1dfr0std's answer is the way to go. But to answer your literal question (pure academic purpose): You are redirecting the output of the `start` command, not of the started program. To include the redirection into the started command, you need to escape it: `start "" "C:\Win Live Response\"NTLast.exe -f ^> test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file named "NTLast_Use.bat" (or whatever makes sense to *you*) and enter your commands there as follows:

```cmd
@Echo Off
setlocal enableextensions
REM %~dp0 is the path and drive of the .bat file itself written as Drive:\Path\
REM If you do not wish to save this text file WITH the .bat file, then modify as necessary.
set "log=%~dp0Test.txt"

NTLast.exe >"%log%"
NTLast.exe -f >>"%log%"
NTLast.exe -r >>"%log%"
NTLast.exe -r -f >>"%log%"

Exit /b
```

Then simply run your `.bat` file (as Admin if needed - right click, and select "Run as Administrator")